# How to add another panel or window to the open3d.visualization.O3DVisualizer class? (In python open3d)

Tags: python, 3d, point-clouds, open3d

#### Context

I am trying to add a gui to the mapping script of the [concept-graphs mapping system](https://github.com/concept-graphs/concept-graphs/tree/c52043b177ee10816dfd9a1509e2ee746ae459b7). The code is ugly at the moment but you can have a look [here](https://github.com/concept-graphs/concept-graphs/blob/c52043b177ee10816dfd9a1509e2ee746ae459b7/conceptgraph/slam/gui_realtime_mapping.py).

This mapping system takes as input rgb images + depth images + poses, and iteratively constructs an object based 3D map that also encodes semantic features. I want to be able to visualize the whole map building process, so I can inspect the map and debug things as it's being built.

So I looked at the python examples and saw that the [multiple_windows.py](https://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_example/visualization/index.html#multiple-windows-py) example seems to have what I want, which is to visualize the object pointclouds and the bounding boxes and so on. I can do that, it works great so far.

#### The Problem

The issue is that I want to also display more information. I would like to be able to see in a panel beside the map: the current rgb image, the current depth image, the current annotated image, the current frame, the current number of objects and so on.

I want it to be like the [dense_slam_gui.py](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/main/examples/python/t_reconstruction_system/dense_slam_gui.py) example in the docs.

I have tried a bunch of stuff but I cannot seem to be able to add a panel to the o3d.visualization.O3DVisualizer thing, and I was also unable to add another window or something that I can update at the same time. I don't mind if its not the same window, I just want to be able to see this information displayed somewhere alongside the map, as it would help me improve the mapping system.

#### My Code

Here are some relevant code snippets.

How I make the app (as you can see I have tried stuff to add another window or panel, but everything I have tried so far has resulted in some kind of error)

```py
def run(self):
    app = o3d.visualization.gui.Application.instance
    app.initialize()

    self.main_vis = o3d.visualization.O3DVisualizer(
        "Open3D - Multi-Window Demo")
    self.main_vis.add_action("Take snapshot in new window",
                             self.on_snapshot)
    self.main_vis.add_action("Pause/Resume updates", lambda vis: self.toggle_pause())
    self.main_vis.set_on_close(self.on_main_window_closing)
    
    app.add_window(self.main_vis)
    # app.add_window(self.images_window)
    
    # # Setup the secondary window for images
    # # self.setup_image_display_window()
    # # self.image_window = app.create_window("RGB and Depth Images", 640, 480)
    # self.image_window = gui.Application.instance.create_window("RGB and Depth Images", 640, 480)
    # # self.image_window.create_window()
    # # self.image_window = o3d.visualization.Visualizer("RGB and Depth Images", 640, 480)
    # self.layout = o3d.visualization.gui.Vert(0, o3d.visualization.gui.Margins(10))
    # self.image_window.add_child(self.layout)

    # # Create image widgets
    # self.rgb_widget = o3d.visualization.gui.ImageWidget()
    # self.depth_widget = o3d.visualization.gui.ImageWidget()

    # # Add image widgets to the layout
    # self.layout.add_child(self.rgb_widget)
    # self.layout.add_child(self.depth_widget)
    # app.add_window(self.image_window)

    self.snapshot_pos = (self.main_vis.os_frame.x, self.main_vis.os_frame.y)
    threading.Thread(target=self.update_thread).start()
    app.run()
```

Here is how I do the update thread:

```py
    def update_thread(self):
        # This is NOT the UI thread, need to call post_to_main_thread() to update
        # the scene or any part of the UI.
        
        ... lots of code, basically the whole mapping script ...
        
            def my_update_cloud():                
                
                # Remove previous objects
                for obj_name in self.prev_obj_names:
                    self.main_vis.remove_geometry(obj_name)
                self.prev_obj_names = []
                
                # Remove previous bounding boxes
                for bbox_name in self.prev_bbox_names:
                    self.main_vis.remove_geometry(bbox_name)
                self.prev_bbox_names = []
                
                # Add the new objects and bounding boxes
                for obj_num, obj in enumerate(self.objects):
                    obj_label = f"{obj['curr_obj_num']}_{obj['class_name']}"
                    
                    obj_name = f"obj_{obj_label}"
                    bbox_name = f"bbox_{obj_label}"
                    
                    self.prev_obj_names.append(obj_name)
                    self.main_vis.add_geometry(obj_name, obj['pcd'])
                    
                    self.prev_bbox_names.append(bbox_name)
                    self.main_vis.add_geometry(bbox_name, obj['bbox'] )
                    
            if self.is_done:  # might have changed while sleeping
                break
            o3d.visualization.gui.Application.instance.post_to_main_thread(
                self.main_vis, my_update_cloud)
```

#### What I want to do

For starters, I just want to be able to update a display with the current rgb and depth image and maybe the current frame number?. I'm imagining something like:

```py
    def update_images(self):
        # Convert numpy images to Open3D images and update widgets
        o3d_rgb_image = o3d.geometry.Image(self.curr_image_rgb)
        o3d_depth_image = o3d.geometry.Image((self.curr_depth_array / self.curr_depth_array.max() * 255).astype(np.uint8))  # Example normalization

        self.rgb_widget.update_image(o3d_rgb_image)
        self.depth_widget.update_image(o3d_depth_image)
        
# and then in the main update thread loop I would do        
self.curr_image_rgb = image_rgb
self.curr_depth_array = depth_array
o3d.visualization.gui.Application.instance.post_to_main_thread(
    self.image_window, self.update_images())
```

I hope it makes sense, what I'm trying to achieve here. If anyone could point me in the right direction, this would be much appreciated. I have googled and asked chatGPT a lot to no avail.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.